# setting django and angular with docker

Tags: django, angular, docker

I have written my first `Django 2.0` application and using `Angular` for frontend.

My Directory structure looks like

```
app
|-- config                # nginx configuration files
    |-- nginx
        |-- nginx.conf
|-- angular-app           # frontend angular application
    |-- angular.json
    |-- package.json
|-- src                   # Django backend application
    |-- myapp
        |-- urls.py
        |-- wsgi.py
    |-- manage.py
|-- static_cdn            # store and host static files and uploaded files
    |-- static_root
    |-- media_root
|-- .dockerignore
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- Dockerfile
|-- requirements.txt
|-- start.sh
```

The content of `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: "myapp-nginx"
    ports:
      - "10080:80"
      - "10443:43"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: "myapp-dev"
    command: ./start.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "9010:9010"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: "myapp-postgres-db"
```

content of `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# -- Install Application into container:
RUN set -ex && mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# -- Adding dependencies:
ADD . /app/
```

content of `start.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

python3 src/manage.py makemigrations
python3 src/manage.py migrate
echo --: Running collectstatic
python3 src/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
echo --: Starting Gunicorn.
gunicorn --pythonpath src myapp.wsgi:application \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:9010 \
    --workers 3
```

This is working fine and django server is accessible on `http://127.0.0.1:9010`

But to run `Angular` application, I need to navigate to the `angular-app` and then run `ng server` to run angular application.

What I want to add `angular-app` to docker setup so that angular app also starts with `docker-compose up` command.

I want different containers for each app so that I could access

```
# Django admin panel via
http://127.0.0.1:9010/admin/

# angular frontend
http://127.0.0.1:4010/
```

But both start with single docker command.

Answer (score 1):

So, your main issue is that you cannot start two processes from in your bash file because both `gunicorn` and `ng server` do not return immediately. They return after they stop. Thus, both the processes will not be started simultaneously.

To solve this, we need something like `supervisor` and run the `gunicorn` and `ng server` with it.
To read how to deploye gunicorn with supervisor, read [this](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#supervisor)

In a similar way, you can start `ng server` with supervisor.

What supervisor does is that it will start both your processes in the background and return immediately.
Enabling you to start both of them with a single command in `start.sh` and hence with `docker-compose up`.

My apologies for not being able to write the complete configuration. Will write it if my time constraints allow it.

[Here's](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) another read that will be useful.

Comment: Hi xssChauhan, for best practice of application development life-cycle. Should I separate frontend and backend repo, docker, and deployment? instead of running both of them in a single `docker-composer` with `supervisor`?

Comment: That would be the ideal way. For that you need to have a separate volume for the staticfiles. This volume needs to be shared by both django and angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Docker networks to link containers to work together

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: "myapp-nginx"
    ports:
      - "10080:80"
      - "10443:43"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: "myapp-dev"
    command: ./start.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "9010:9010"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: "myapp-postgres-db"

  networks:
    yourapp
```

Read [networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/)

Comment: don't I need to add `angular-app` to `docker-compose.yml`?